# Error message on SQL Server 2012 install

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, sql-server-2012

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition on my Windows Server 2012. The installation keeps failing, and I have tried everything that I can come up with, but nothing helps. The error message is not very useful to me, and I cannot find much on it. Can anyone tell me what to do to fix this error?

This is the error message I get:

```
Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x80004005
  Error description:             The system cannot find the path specified
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=0xF57C3D6F%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0xF57C3D6F%400xDC80C325
```

The whole log file:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2147467259
  Start time:                    2013-11-23 22:56:16
  End time:                      2013-11-23 23:14:57
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  HARLEYQUINN
  Machine processor count:       4
  OS version:                    Future Windows Version
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Standard Edition     11.1.3000.0     No        
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Management Tools - Complete              1033                 Standard Edition     11.1.3000.0     No        

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2012
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       11
  Installation location:         F:\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Standard

  Slipstream:                    True
  SP Level                       1
  Patch Level:                   11.1.3128.0

Product Update Status:
  Success: KB 2674319, KB 2793634

Product Updates Selected for Installation:
  Title:                         Service Pack 1
  Knowledge Based Article:       KB 2674319
  Version:                       11.1.3000.0
  Architecture:                  x64
  Language:                      1033

  Title:                         SQL Server 2012 SP1 GDR Product Update
  Knowledge Based Article:       KB 2793634
  Version:                       11.1.3128.0
  Architecture:                  x64
  Language:                      All

  Update Source:                 MU


User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131123_225308\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                false
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          <empty>
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           HARLEYQUINN\DoomStone
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  false
  TCPENABLED:                    1
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131123_225308\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x80004005
  Error description:             The system cannot find the path specified
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=0xF57C3D6F%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0xF57C3D6F%400xDC80C325

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131123_225308\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Comment: *"Failed: see logs for details"* So what do the *logs* say?

Comment: That is the log file. But i have put it all there now

Answer (score 2):

Upon installation sql automatically adds some features to your windows system (.net framework 3.5 in particular). If it cannot access files needed to add those features (installation cd or windows update) you will get this error.

upd. When you add "roles and features" to your win server2012 it either tries to locate installation files on windows installation image or downloads them form windows update. If no path to those files is specified (cd removed or windows was installed from wds) and windows update is unaccessible (gp points to local wsus or some proxy forbids you from accessing winupdate) your installation will fail.

Same thing does SQL installation (I'm sure it adds at least .net feature) before installing sql server itself

Comment: Hmm my computer is connected to the internet, and i am installing from a mounted iso of the sql server 2012 from MSDN. Any idea of what might be inaccessable?

Comment: Try to manually add .net 3.5 from "add roles and features"

Comment: I have added .net 3.5 (all .net) but the install still fails :(

Comment: Maybe it's time to give us more info about your infrastructure. Is this clean installation of sql and server or upgrade? workgroup or domain? any proxy server present in network?

Comment: It is a clean install of sql server, but the server is not a new install. The server is not in a doamin or uses a proxy. The server have mysql install.

Comment: Is there any leftovers from failed installation? If yes, try to uninstall any ms sql components that might be present in system and run installation again.

Comment: I haved tyed clearing it all, but i have decided to do a clean reinstall now.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the following command:

`net share MSSQLSERVER /delete`

To remove existing (possible incorrect/corrupted) MSSQLSERVER shared folder.

Then run the SQL Server setup again.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/78668cfa-5e3d-4d05-bd72-770d8e2417db/upgrade-2008-r2-to-2012-database-engine-services-failed?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>net share MSSQLSERVER /delete
This shared resource does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to extract the installation with 7z, into a folder. and then run the

> setup.exe

file. and the installation starts.